# How should I go about proving set theory laws?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am studying idempotent laws, identity laws, De Morgan's laws and other such algebraic identities related to sets and Cartesian products of 2 sets. But the text I am using doesn't provide any proofs. How should I try proving these identities myself ? For the trivial ones like the union of two sets is the sum of the sets minus the intersection of 2 sets, intuition is good enough but for the larger identities, I would like yo have a proof for better understanding of the concepts.

Comment: "the union of two sets is the sum of the sets minus the intersection of 2 sets" I think you mean the disjoint union is the union minus the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Replace $\cap$ with $\land$, $\cup$ with $\lor$, $\setminus$ with $\land\neg$ etc., then quantify over arbitrary elements to reduce a theorem about sets to an associated truth function being tautological. For example,$$(A\cap B)\cup C=(A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C)$$means$$\forall x(x\in(A\cap B)\cup C\iff x\in(A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C)).$$Writing $a$ for $x\in A$ etc., you need only prove$$(a\land b)\lor c=(a\lor c)\land(b\lor c).$$

Cartesian product identities introduce a small complication. Since $(x,\,y)\in A\times B$ iff $x\in A\land y\in B$, which we might abbreviate as $a\land b$, we can restate such identities as $\forall x\forall y(\cdots)$, where the $\cdots$ becomes some truth function. For example,$$A\times(B\cap C)=(A\times B)\cap(A\times C)$$simplifies to$$a\land(b\land c)=(a\land b)\land(a\land c),$$where $a$ means $x\in A$, $b$ means $y\in B$, $c$ means $y\in C$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But the thing is......I don't know what  ∨, ∧,  ∀, and ∧¬ means so I really couldn't understand.

Comment: @AritroShome $\land$ means and so is analogous to the similarly shaped $\cap$, $\lor$ means exclusively or so is analogous to the similarly shaped $\cup$, $\forall$ means for **a**ll (it's a rotated **A**), and the last issue concerns understanding $\neg$ after you understand $\land$: $p\land\neg q$ means $p$ and **not** $q$.

Comment: Ohkay i see so we use these symbols in place of the English words

Comment: MEA culpa: $\lor$ is _inclusive_ or.